# Do resource routes use Delete or Destroy to remove a Mongoid document?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, callback, mongoid, rails-routing

This is simple enough.

I'm trying to use mongoid's 'after_destroy' callback to do some cleanup operations.

Eg

```
class Model
    include Mongoid::Document

    after_destroy do |model|
        #Do cleanup stuff
    end
end
```

There are 2 ways to remove an object from mongo. Delete and Destroy. Destroy runs the callback but Delete Doesn't.

The model's routes are declared like this

```
  resources :models
```

So my question is, when someone sends a request to models/delete does the destroy method get called or the delete method?

If the latter, then is there any way to run callbacks with the delete function in mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP method :delete that gets created in `resources :models` has no direct bearing on the method used in the model. the HTTP delete calls this method:

```
class ModelsController < ApplicationController

  def delete
    model = Model.find(params[:id])
    model.destroy
    redirect_to models_path, notice: "Model removed"
  end
end
```

You're able to change "delete" to "destroy" in the controller to suit your needs.

Comment: I have something similar already. I appreciate the help but I'm not asking 'how' to make the '/models/delete' route use a different function. I'm just trying to figure out 'which' of the functions is called by default.

Because I'm using 'resources :models' in my routes file, the ModelsController is empty. Ergo, the delete function is handled by ApplicationController. I would have guessed that the ApplicationController is calling delete by default. I have tried reading through the source for ApplicationController or ActionController but they are verbose and difficult. Great answer though!

Comment: There's certainly no default anything being called. If the method does not exist on the controller, your model is not being deleted unless you are using inherited resources (https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources)

Comment: Also the route is not "/models/delete" ... it's a DELETE http call to /models/56 (if the model id is 56)

Comment: Sounds like I've got some investigating to do as my model is definitely being deleted! Thanks for the help!

PS You are correct about using the _method: DELETE http call to /models/56. I was just using /models/delete because its shorter.